# Android Dev: Time span past midnight calculation

Tags: android, timer

im working on auto profile changer application for android...this is my 2nd application im developing on android, so dont know all the bells and whistles of android development...

any way...i am having some trouble calculating the next time when the timer code is suppose to execute...mainly the issue is around the time that spans over midnight into the next day...

for example, say that the user created a sleeping profile that starts at 10:30PM and goes until 8AM the next day...using this as a example, the execution is getting inside the proper condition that i have placed in the code, but the nextUpdateInterval is not being set correctly...im still trying to figure out how to account/calculate time that spans over to the next day, and at this point im starting to think that im might be making this task overly complicated? any suggestions?

here is the snippet of the code:

```
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
    //..... some code to convert user stored times into proper time formats
    //PM to PM
    if(isFromTimePM == true && isToTimePM == true){

    }//PM to AM
    else if(isFromTimePM == true && isToTimePM == false){
        if(rightNowDate.getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() && rightNowDate.getTime() >= toDate.getTime()){
            foundProfileIndex = i;
                i = profileArrayListSize;


            nextUpdateInterval = rightNowDate.getTime() - toDate.getTime();
        }                   
    }//AM to AM
    else if(isFromTimePM == false && isToTimePM == false){

    }//AM to PM
    else if(isFromTimePM == false && isToTimePM == true){

    }}, 0, nextUpdateInterval);
```

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

none of this secondDate - firstDate was ever necessary, what i ended up doing was the following:

1. converted all times to miliseconds
2. converted the milliseconds into the date objects
3. used the compareTo to compare the 'to' 'from' dates to current date/time
4. if i found a profile match, then i stored the 'to' date as the next run date
5. created a reScheduleTimer method that took date as a paramter...and i just used the .schdule(timertask, date) to resechule the timer...

Answer (score 0):

Forget about PM and AM. Since you appear to be using dates, when you use the getTime() method you are getting the number of milliseconds elapsed since the Epoch. Simply subtract these two and you will have the time interval in milliseconds:

```
long nextUpdateInterval = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
```

The nextUpdateInterval is a long and is 'time in milliseconds between successive task executions'.

Comment: actually...the AM/PM if conditions are only to flex the logic to see if the 'rightNow' time will fall in within the user set times...and as u can see, i do exactly what u mentioned for setting the nextUpdateInterval: nextUpdateInterval = rightNowDate.getTime() - toDate.getTime();....but this is not setting the correct next execution time